# Как передавать объекты большого объема в Kafka

Tags: база-данных, highload, big-data, apache-kafka

Сразу нужно отметить -- вопрос чисто академический!!! Очевидно, что брокеры сообщений не предназначены для таких вещей. Но это стоит обсудить, чтобы иметь более полное понимание всех возможностей. Вопрос основан на [аналогичном](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59304389/mark-end-of-logical-section-at-kafka-when-multiple-partitions-are-used) из другого языкового раздела.

Если объем данных каждой из передаваемых сущностьей превышает максимальный объем сообщений в Kafka, как *consumer* может узнать о завершении передачи очередного объекта?

Первая мысль - использовать дополнительный *topic*, куда слать сигналы о завершении.

Еще можно пересылать условный код в последних сообщениях. Тогда если у нас *Х* партиций, то код нужно отправлять в *Х* последних сообщениях.

Оба способа топорные. Хотелось бы найти более изящное решение.

Comment: Если объект можно безболезненно дробить, то может просто добавить ключ в каждое сообщение? При смене ключа, понимаем что пошла новая порция данных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно развернуть объектное хранилище (локальный S3 alike, варианты есть [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10574909/5308802) и [здесь](https://m.habr.com/ru/post/318086/comments/)). Процесс получается такой: producer'ы загружают в хранилище большой пакет данных, затем в Кафку передают только путь до этого объекта, а consumer'ы получают сообщение, выгружают файл, обрабатывают, и по завершению удаляют из хранилища.

Comment: Хорошее решение, но по первой ссылке большинство источников устарело (

Comment: Наверное сечайчас более актуально https://github.com/minio/

Comment: @VasinYuriy Для полноты картины решил сослаться на общие списки, но да, МинИО сейчас в тренде.